# Nodejs + Express - Cannot call method 'json' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working with Express, Hoganjs, Nodejs.

The code below keeps returning "500 TypeError: Cannot call method 'json' of undefined"

I figure there is something wrong with how I am calling getUsers, but I'm too much of a newbie to figure it out. None of the tutorials or forums I have referred to are helping as of yet.

```
exports.admin = function(req, res){
getUsers(function(error, res){
    res.render('admin', {
        title: 'Admin',
        userlist: res
    });
});
};



function getUsers(req, res) {
res.json([
    {username: "fake", permission: "admin" },
    {username: "fake2", permission: "user" }
])
}

exports.getUsers = getUsers;
```

Comment: btw.. this file is in my /routes folder and is related to a hoganjs view.

Comment: Where do you pass in `res` in `getUsers()`?

Comment: I'm not sure where I would. I guess I thought that res was the response and that I didn't need to pass it in. I'm coming from a PHP world and this callback stuff is confusing me despite reading 2 books on node.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so your code snippet is not properly formatted and thus hard to read, but I think `exports.admin` is being called as an express route that takes `req, res`. So far so good. Then you call `getUsers` and pass it a callback, but `getUsers` doesn't take a callback, it takes `req, res` as well. It's unclear what you're trying to do, but something like this would be reasonable:

```
exports.admin = function(req, res) {
  loadUsers(function (error, users) {
    if (error) {
      return res.status(500).send(error);
    }
    res.render('admin', {
        title: 'Admin',
        userlist: users
    });
  }
};

exports.getUsers = function(req, res) {
    loadUsers(function (error, users) {
      if (error) {
        return res.status(500).send(error);
      }
      res.send(users);
    });
}

function loadUsers(callback) {
  process.nextTick(function () {
    callback(null, [
      {username: "fake", permission: "admin" },
      {username: "fake2", permission: "user" }]
    );
  });
}
```

An even better pattern would be to code `loadUsers` as middleware, FYI.

Comment: I edited it again to simulate an asynchronous `loadUsers` function.